# Removing column of Excel sheet using NPOI(1.2.5.0)

Tags: .net, excel, npoi

I'm trying to find a column and delete it, but I don't know what a method for remove a column.

I tried remove cell, code as below. But I want remove complete column.

```
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow)Sheet.GetRow(r);
HSSFCell newCell = (HSSFCell)row.GetCell(nIndex);
row.RemoveCell(newCell);
```

the code above just clears content of cell. do not remove cell. I am now looping all the rows to clear all cells of specific column.

Now, I was searching something called column shift, but there does not seems to be a method for this. Please let me know if there is a method of NPOI for column shift.

.net Framework-3.5 VS 2008
NPOI(1.2.5.0)

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to remove 1 or 2 columns, but `row.RemoveCell(newCell);` only removes cell content. The only solution i can think of is to clear all cells in column and move appropriate columns left. But that could cause problems if you are using formulas.

Comment: @JNM can you give me syntax or method to shift column in NPOI, I don't know how it will handle formulas if any.

Answer (score 3):

For now i can think of only one method: clear column and copy values from other column. So the column would not be deleted, but shifted to the right (to other empty columns). I don't know how it would work with formulas, but it should be ok with simple text or digits.
Sample code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePaths[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
HSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs, true);
ISheet sheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheet("Input");
for (int h = 0; h <= sheet.LastRowNum; h++)
{
    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(h);
    row.RemoveCell(row.GetCell(cellIndex)); //Remove cell value
    row.Cells[cellIndex].SetCellValue(row.Cells[cellIndex + 1].StringCellValue); //Copy right column values to left
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I made a generic function so it can be used for any excel file. I now need to check if the excel has formulas, if no formula I can use above logic you suggested. 2. I got response from project member of NPOI saying "So far, there is no support for that. If you really need that, you can buy professional service," . I will check whether customization of NPOI solves the issue.